# How to restart my android application on settings change?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am developing a bilingual application. I want it to get fully restarted on language settings change. Here is the code I am using:

```
Intent restartIntent = getBaseContext().getPackageManager()
                            .getLaunchIntentForPackage(getBaseContext().getPackageName() );
    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 0, restartIntent,     Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + 1, intent);
    System.exit(2);
```

This works fine except that after the app is restarted, I have two main activities (the old one still remains). How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add finish(); to your current Activity

```
Intent restartIntent = getBaseContext().getPackageManager()
                            .getLaunchIntentForPackage(getBaseContext().getPackageName() );
    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 0, restartIntent,     Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + 1, intent);
    finish();
    System.exit(2);
```

Comment: yes, it worked. Can you please explain what was the problem and how finish() could solve it? tnx : )

Comment: the finish() instruction will close your Activity first because Android use an ActivityManager to handle the stack of Activities so when you don't use the finish(); instruct it remains alive in the Stack (Activity Manager) and it will be popped up again whenever your app is launched that's all for your answer

Comment: But the activity that is running the above code snippet is one other than the "main" activity (which before applying your solution, I had two instances of it after app restart). So finish() should close let say "Settings" activity not "main" activity. Meanwhile is that "Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP" useless?

Comment: finish will close it's running Activity because it's stands for this.finish();